# Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

after export from eclipse i have error:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>java C:\wamp\www\JOGL\test.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\wamp\www\JOGL\test/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\wamp\www\JOGL\test.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: C:\wamp\www\JOGL\test.jar.  Program will exit.
```

manifest from this file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true
Main-Class: windows.SimpleScene
```

the same error when export with Fat Jar

updated:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>java -jar C:\wamp\www\JOGL\test.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLEventListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
Could not find the main class: windows.SimpleScene. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a jar file, you run:

```
java -jar (name-of-jar-file)
```

So you should run:

```
java -jar C:\wamp\www\JOGL\test.jar
```

Comment: @Taras: That's a different class - one in the OpenGL library. You'll need to add appropriate classpath entries in your jar file for that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure, when you are exporting and creating you JAR three things are set:

1. Export it as a "runnable jar file".
2. Define your launch configuration (which is your class that has the main method in it).
3. select "Package Required libraries into generated JAR".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The command you entered only "java file.jar" is used to run .class files, the right syntax to run jar is the "java -jar file.jar" that search your jar for the manifest and execute it.

You can also run it by adding in the class-path and the main class name

```
java -cp C:\wamp\www\JOGL\test.jar com.ext.Example
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you run a JAR file!

Use `java -jar test.jar` syntax

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this error is java is looking at your current working directory as the classpath. where as your JAR file is located in a different directory.

You have the following options:
1)
cd C:\wamp\www\JOGL
java -jar test.jar  (as you defined the Main-Class in the manifest file, java would pick it from there).
Make sure your jar maintains the same directory structure as your package structure.

2) java -cp C:\wamp\www\JOGL\test.jar window.SimpleClass (pointing the classpath to your jar)

Note: If you have dependencies on other JARs/classes beyond this JAR file, they need to be part of the classpath (absolute/relative to current directory).